# If you're falling because of ball bearings, do you automatically land on caltrops in the same space?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, equipment, saving-throw

If a creature had to make both saving throws for ball bearings and caltrops, and failed the ball bearings - Would they automatically fall prone & land on the caltrops, taking caltrop damage with no chance for a caltrops saving throw (or regardless of a passed caltrops saving throw)?

---

Inspired by [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/141378/28224) to this question [If an area is covered in both Ball Bearings and Caltrops, does the creature need to move at half speed or quarter speed to avoid both their effects?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/141377/if-an-area-is-covered-in-both-ball-bearings-and-caltrops-does-the-creature-need) where it's mentioned:

> Note that if the creature chose to move greater than half their speed across the combined area then they would be forced to make ***both*** *saving throws*, one against the ball bearings and one against the caltrops, possibly suffering one effect or the other effect or both effects combined.

Answer (score 22):

### No

There is nothing in the rules to suggest you do.

A DM is free to impose disadvantage on either (or both) saving throws if circumstances warrant - perhaps they do?

Answer (score 2):

### The rules don't say. Make a ruling.

The descriptions for ball bearings and for caltrops don't mention each other, so a strict reading of the rules doesn't answer the question. Apply the level of physical reasoning your group finds acceptable.